# Type checking error useing random in purescript

Tags: purescript

With the following code insertRnd works properly but I can't get scramble or anything else that uses insertRnd to compile:

```
scramble :: ∀ eff. String -> Eff (random :: RANDOM | eff) String
scramble s = foldl insertRnd (take 1 s) (drop 1 s)

insertRnd :: ∀ eff. String -> String -> Eff (random :: RANDOM | eff) String
insertRnd st ch = do
  n <- randomInt 0 $ length st
  pure $ insertAt n ch st
```

I get the following error message

```
Could not match type

Eff
  ( random :: RANDOM
  | t2
  )
  String

with type

String

while checking that type forall eff.
                       String
                       -> String
                          -> Eff
                               ( random :: RANDOM
                               | eff
                               )
                               String
is at least as general as type t0 -> t1 -> t0
while checking that expression insertRnd
has type t0 -> t1 -> t0
in value declaration scramble

where t0 is an unknown type
  t1 is an unknown type
  t2 is an unknown type
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, your `insertRnd` itself doesn't compile for me, because there is no function `insertAt :: Int -> String -> String -> String` (or even [`Int -> Char -> String -> String`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/search?q=Int+-%3E+Char+-%3E+String+-%3E+String), see below). [There is such function for arrays and lists and some other stuff](https://pursuit.purescript.org/search?q=insertAt), but not for strings. I will just assume here that you wrote such function yourself and it exists in your code.

**Second**, even if it does compile, it has wrong signature for a `fold`: you're trying to fold over a `String`, which contains `Char`s, which means that the folding function's second argument must be a `Char`. So here I'll assume that your `insertRnd` actually has the following signature:

```
insertRnd :: ∀ eff. String -> Char -> Eff (random :: RANDOM | eff) String
```

**Third**, you can't actually `foldl` over a `String`, because `String` doesn't have an instance of `Foldable`. To fold over the characters of a string, you need to first convert the string to an array (or some other container) of `Char`. Fortunately, there is a helpful function for that - [`toCharArray`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-strings/3.5.0/docs/Data.String#v:toCharArray).

**Fourth**, your claim about not being able to compile "anything else that uses `insertRnd`" is probably too broad. Here's a perfectly compilable example of "anything else" that uses `insertRnd`:

```
main = launchAff do
    x <- liftEff $ insertRnd "abcd" 'x'
    log x
```

**And finally**, the reason that your `foldl` doesn't compile is that `foldl` expects a pure function `a -> b -> a` as first argument, but you're giving it an effectful function `a -> b -> Eff _ a`. No wonder there is a type mismatch!

The effectful analog of `foldl` is [`foldM`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foldable-traversable/3.4.0/docs/Data.Foldable#v:foldM). This function does a similar thing, except it chains the calls within a monad instead of doing pure functional composition. For example:

```
foldM insertRnd "a" ['b', 'c', 'd']
```

**Applying all of the above** to your code, here's the final version (assuming the existence of `insertAt :: Int -> Char -> String -> String`):

```
scramble :: ∀ eff. String -> Eff (random :: RANDOM | eff) String
scramble s = foldM insertRnd (take 1 s) (toCharArray $ drop 1 s)

insertRnd :: ∀ eff. String -> Char -> Eff (random :: RANDOM | eff) String
insertRnd st ch = do
  n <- randomInt 0 $ length st
  pure $ insertAt n ch st
```

Comment: Yes i forgot about `insertAt`. Also didn't even know about `foldM`, thank you for that.